# MS Access 2010 - How to display form fields programmatically based on previous input?

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2010, office-2010

I have a form where the first field is a type that the user will choose from a combo box. I'd like the subsequent fields to display based off of what the type is. Pseudo:

```
  if typefield == bank
      display fields 1-4
  else
      display fields 5-8
```

How would I go about doing this in Access 2010? I'm not sure modal would apply since I would like this all one form. If this is not possible, any suggestions on a solution that gets close?

Comment: What are `fields`? Controls? So after a user selects something in the combobox, display some controls, if there is nothing selected, only show the other controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all eight fields on the form and you are just wanting to make them visible based on a choice  from the "typefield" then something like this would work.

```
If me.typefield.value = bank Then
            Me.field5.Visible  = False 
            Me.field6.Visible  = False 
            Me.field7.Visible  = False 
            Me.field8.Visible  = False   
            Me.field1.Visible  = True    
            Me.field2.Visible  = True
            Me.field3.Visible  = True 
            Me.field4.Visible  = True
Else
            Me.field1.Visible  = False 
            Me.field2.Visible  = False 
            Me.field3.Visible  = False 
            Me.field4.Visible  = False   
            Me.field5.Visible  = True   
            Me.field6.Visible  = True 
            Me.field7.Visible  = True
            Me.field8.Visible  = True
End if
```

You could of course just have 4 text boxes that you could change the control source and labels based on their choice....

```
IF me.typefield.value = bank then
           Me.textbox1.ControlSource = "field1"
           Me.label1.Caption = "field1 or whatever"
          ' repeat for the other 3
Else
           Me.textbox5.ControlSource = "field5"
           Me.label5.Caption = "field5 or whatever"
           ' repeat for the other 3
End if
```

Comment: How can you answer the question without knowing exactly what the OP wants to do?

Comment: I may have been vague but TBair8 nailed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tab control and place Fields 1-4 on Page1 and Fields 5-8 on Page2. By doing this you only need to use two statements to select which tab is displayed:

```
Private Sub TypeCombo_Click()
    If [Type].Text = "bank" Then
       Page2.Visible = False
       Page1.Visible = True
    Else
       Page1.Visible = False
       Page2.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

You can label the Pages with text that makes sense for the selected type.